# Regex must start with a letter or number, string can only have letters, numbers or slashes, and no double slashes

Tags: regex

I am trying to check some strings.  Here are the parameters.

1. A string must start with a letter or number
2. A string can only contain letters, numbers or slashes
3. A string cannot have a double slash (ex: "api//go")

Good Strings:

```
go
go2/api/hello
go/api45
```

Bad Strings:

```
/go        (can't begin with a slash)
go//api    (can't have a double slash)
go/api%    (can't contain non number, letter or slash)
```

I've been trying to use RegExr.com but to no avail.  I have been trying with this expression:

```
^[^\/](([0-9A-Za-z])+(\/)?)+
```

but it does not quite work.

Comment: Surely if you're been "trying to use RegExr.com" you can include some of the things you've tried that haven't worked?

Comment: Sure ken here is what i got so far ^[^\/](([0-9A-Za-z])+(\/)?)+

Comment: Thanks. :-) For future reference: when asked to add information or details to your question, please [edit] your question to do so instead of putting it in a comment where it can't be easily seen and can't be properly formatted. You can find the [edit] link right below the tags in your question.

Comment: @Jake.JS nice question! -HR25

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try something like this (I hope whatever flavor you're using has lookahead!):

```
^(?!.*\/\/)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\/]*$
```

**Please see [Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gP2gD2/2) for complete description and test strings.**

Comment: Too bad regex101 forces you to write `\/` instead of just `/`

Comment: I do it out of habit anyway :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski you can change the delimiter to something else by cicking on the left one to avoid escaping slashes: https://regex101.com/r/gP2gD2/3

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
^[0-9a-z](\/?[0-9a-z])*\/?$
```

Requires the `/i` (case insensitive modifier) in the current form. This is pretty simple and doesn't need lookaheads.

Explanation:

```
^         Starts with
[0-9a-z]  1 Alphanumeric character
(         Start a repeatable group
\/?       Optional /
[0-9a-z]  1 Alphanumeric character
)*        Repeat the group zero or more times
\/?       Allow for an ending slash
$         String must end
```

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Nice catch, I removed the + to eliminate that